# Avoid Wordpress site access

Tags: php, .htaccess, wordpress

I just pick up a client website which integrated with wordpress from a previous developer.
the structure of the site is like this
root
L blog(wordpress) 
L images
L css
L etc...

so the only purpose of WordPress is posting post/news. But the post loop is on the home page of the website.

right now mysite.com/blog is accessible, although there have no link on the website to this page.but my client still to avoid people accessing mysite.com/blog, since the page have no purpose at all and the theme template does not match the website.

How can I limit the access to  mysite.com/blog page.

Comment: place an `.htaccess` file within the `blog` directory, then `deny from all`, followed by `allow from my.ip.add.ress`

Comment: i have no knowledgeon .htaccess, did a bit research. am I right if i write like this:
# BEGIN WordPress<Limit GET POST>
order deny,allow
allow from my.site.ip.add
deny from all
</Limit># END WordPress

Comment: Thanks Ohgodwhy it does block the access to the mtsite.com/blog page, but the problem now is the post thumbnails on home page all become broken link once i use the .htaccess.